# Integration postman with gitlab(newman)

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, postman, newman

I am thinking about integration postman with gitlab. The stack app is spring boot/docker and everything (with mvn build etc.) run in gitlab pipeline.

But I am wondering about integration postman with gitlab. There is possibility that postman will call build gitlab artifacts? I mean - no calling to deployed app, but testing current building application?

Comment: Did you try to use [newman](https://hub.docker.com/r/postman/newman) in your pipeline running test on your previously built image ?

Comment: This is not a solution and I don't like adding external links to things but I created this basic thing a while back - https://gitlab.com/DannyDainton/postman-ci-pipeline-example